# Powershell how to do one single line?

Tags: powershell

I have a string

```
"1 1 1 2 2 2
333 11 44 67 123 7676
4334"
```

How do I make her > `"11122233311446712376764334"`
Using to powershell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find additional details on Powershell's string manipulation abilities from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2)'s documentation.

```
$s = "1 1 1 2 2 2
333 11 44 67 123 7676
4334"
$s = $s -replace "\s",""

Write-Host $s
>> 11122233311446712376764334
```